# Not able to point the start tag correctly in package.json for react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

When I write the package.json for a particular react app, it works fine on npm with the bundle getting ready and renders without issues, but when I make another app, by putting all my code in a subfolder and i copy the same package.json for my new react app, npm is throwing an error. It seems like it is not able to identify the start component from my bundle. Please help.

```
    {
     "name": "ReactDemoBarath",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "Creating New Project for React Demo",
     "main": "index.js",
     "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "webpack-server": "webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --color",
     "web-server": "http-server -p 3000 .",
     "start": "npm run webpack-server & npm run web-server"// looks like something is wrong here
      },
     "author": "Barath Kumar R",
     "license": "ISC",
     "keywords": [],
     "dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.9.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"express": "^4.13.4",
"flux": "^2.1.1",
"lodash": "^3.10.1",
"object-assign": "^4.0.1",
"react": "^0.14.7",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.29.5",
"react-dom": "^0.14.7",
"react-router": "^2.0.0"
   },
 "devDependencies": {
"autoprefixer-loader": "^3.1.0",
"babel-core": "^6.5.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"file-loader": "^0.9.0",
"http-server": "^0.8.0",
"img-loader": "^1.2.0",
"jquery": "^2.2.1",
"node-sass": "^3.2.0",
"postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.2.8",
"svgo": "^0.6.1",
"svgo-loader": "^1.1.0",
"sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
"source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
"script-loader": "^0.6.1",
"style-loader": "^0.13.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "^1.12.13",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.10.1"
}
}
```

My error log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-     cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.1
3 info using node@v4.4.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart ReactDemoBarath@1.0.0
6 info start ReactDemoBarath@1.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info ReactDemoBarath@1.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: ReactDemoBarath@1.0.0 start: `npm run webpack-server     & npm run web-server`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program  Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid ReactDemoBarath@1.0.0
11 verbose cwd E:\Workspace_React\React_Engage
12 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v4.4.3
15 error npm  v2.15.1
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error ReactDemoBarath@1.0.0 start: `npm run webpack-server & npm run web-server`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the ReactDemoBarath@1.0.0 start script 'npm run webpack-server & npm run web-server'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the ReactDemoBarath package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     npm run webpack-server & npm run web-server
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs ReactDemoBarath
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls ReactDemoBarath
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: have you changed the path of your entry point ?? you need to change the path of your entry file in the webpack.config.js file

Comment: Oops yes. thank you

Comment: i am posting that as an answer. mark it as it would help others.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the path of your entry point. you need to change the path of your entry file in

> webpack.config.js

Answer (score -1):

This is correct, it worked for me.Chnaging the entry file in the webpack.config.js.   I also had to add  the webpack-dev-server in
 my project node-modules folder. You should get this when start works.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0qZQ.png

I hope this helps some one

PDH